# Create a firestore document with a collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create a firestore doc which also has a collection, ideally in a single write operation.

I'm not seeing anything like this in the documentation, so failing that any tips on getting the created doc id and then adding multiple documents to a collection?

Edit: I'm developing in typescript/js

Comment: In what language / environment? Javascript? Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [transaction or batch write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to perform atomic operations among multiple documents.  In both cases, you need to know all the IDs for all the documents you want to create ahead of time.  You don't need to create a document in order for there to be a subcollection.  Documents don't actually "contain" subcollection.  Subcollections are currently just a technique for organizing your data.

It wasn't really clear from your question, but if your first document requires a generated ID, you can use the example code [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) that generates a DocumentReference object, which you can populate later in your transaction or batch.

Since you didn't say which language or system you're working on, I don't know which code sample to show here from the docs, so you'll have to go to the documentation linked here to see how it works.  You'll end up using a method called "doc" or "document" on a CollectionReference to generate the DocumentReference with the generated ID.